# " Error Compilation error: encoded string too long:" when making a build

Tags: grails, groovy, war

I have a Grails project that is running correctly in dev mode but when I try to create a war file it gives me following message and stops the build

```
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Compiling 16 GSP files for package [ProjectName]
| Compiling 16 GSP files for package [ProjectName].
| Error Compilation error: encoded string too long: 108421 bytes
```

Grails doesn't give me any other info in terms of which GSP or line has the problem, anyone seen this happening?

Here are the grails stats, I would say its a fairly small project

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Name                 | Files |  LOC  |
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Controllers          |     6 |   624 | 
| Domain Classes       |     6 |   109 | 
| Java Helpers         |     1 |    96 | 
| Unit Tests           |    12 |   565 | 
| Scripts              |     1 |     4 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Totals               |    26 |  1398 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Looks like you have some massive static HTML pages or something in there?

Comment: @tim_yates Not really, most of the views are rendered from scaffolding . The biggest GSP has 65 lines in it.

Comment: @tim_yates is there a way to figure out what GSP/file is causing this problem?

Comment: no huge html static files (which are not counted in the stats report)?

Comment: @tim_yates not even a single HTML file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never knew what the problem was, all I did is moved all the needed file to a brand new project and this error disappeared!

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is grails bug with versions [prior to  2.3.7](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11171)  but it's fixed in  2.3.7 and above. 
You have two options upgrade or follow the below steps

1. Find all the gsp pages with file size greater than 64K.
2. Add <% /* comment to break the static gsp block */ %>  to the middle of your static pages (add it to the end of html tags, for example after `</P>` etc).

This will make grails think that it's processing two chunks and allows it to get processed.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before. Exactly what @tim_yates commented! Refactored some gsp's [include for example] and all was good again. Also, making a little research about this I found some interesting things about DataOutputStream.java. It seems to have a [64kb limit](http://www.drillio.com/en/software-development/java/encoded-string-too-long-64kb-limit/) for String objects.

Maybe [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/fop-users@xmlgraphics.apache.org/msg11317.html) can also help you.

Cheers!

Comment: Not really, most of the views are rendered from scaffolding . The biggest GSP has 65 lines in it.

Comment: That is weird. Take a look at workdir/gspcompile and see the last compiled file. That might give you some clue...

Comment: My apologies but where is this workdir supposed to be located?

Comment: $HOME/.grails/(version)/projects/projectname/gspcompile but you can specify this in your BuildConfig.groovy using the grails.project.work.dir variable.

Comment: Well only file getting generated is gsp_projectNameerror_gsp.groovy, it's a 2KB file and I have not even customized an error page so this is the default file!!

Comment: I thought it might to have with Mahout plugin that I had installed but this error does not come in a brand new project with the same plugin